# scikit-learn : ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

There is a `check_array` function for calculating `mean absolute percentage error (MAPE)`  in the recent version of `sklearn` but it doesn't seem to work the same way as the previous version.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import check_array

def calculate_mape(y_true, y_pred): 
    y_true, y_pred = check_array(y_true, y_pred)

    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100
y_true = [3, -0.5, 2, 7]; y_pred = [2.5, -0.3, 2, 8]
calculate_mape(y_true, y_pred)
```

This is returning an error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`. Is there any fix for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the

```
check_array
```

Returns one single object

See the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.check_array.html)

Comment: aha, OK. It seems that that function is no longer used for calculating `Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)` metric in `python sklearn`